# How to call mysql stored procedure in laravel 5.3 ORM illuminate with parameter

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have created a stored procedure called `new_user` and tested it, works fine when I do a call in sequel pro and workbench.

I am now trying to call the stored procedure using laravel 5.3. I did a test using laravel insert create function and it works fine, which tells me I have set up laravel ORM correctly.

I then googled around looked on laravel site doc and saw a few stackoverflow solution and tried implement it, but none seem to work. Here is what I have tried so far

The model php is pretty simple

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as EloquentModel;

class Model extends EloquentModel {
   protected $table = null;
}
```

and in another class i used the following functions

```
 $user = new \App\Models\Model;
//this calls but nothing gets inserted into the database
 $user::select('call new_user("myemail@test.com","mypassword","myname","mysurname");');

//same thing happens but nothing gets inserted into the database
     $user::select($user::raw('call new_user("myemail@test.com","mypassword","myname","mysurname");'));

 // this makes slim 3 throw BadMethodCallException
    $user::statement('call new_user("myemail@test.com","mypassword","myname","mysurname");');

// this makes slim 3 throw BadMethodCallException
 $user::statement('call new_user(_email,_password,_name,_surname)values(?,?,?,?)',["myemail@test.com","mypassword","myname","mysurname"]);
```

Now am not sure how to call a stored procedure. I am just wondering what am i doing wrong. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the model class to call a stored procedure.
Just call:

```
DB::statement('call new_user(?, ?, ?, ?)',["myemail@test.com","mypassword","myname","mysurname"]);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried this statement, but it didnt work.

Comment: I get what you mean now, I wasnt calling it properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way in Laravel's Eloquent besides a raw `statement`function. However you could create your own basemodel that can be used in your usermodel like this

```
class MyModel extends Model {

    public static function callStoredProcedure($name, $arrayOfKeyValues) {

        $statement = '\'call $name("';  // call stored procedure by argument $name
        $arguments = implode('", "' $arrayOfKeyValues) . '")\''; // values are merged as string
        $statement .= $arguments;
        self::::statement($statement);
    }
}
```

and call it in your userModel:
`class UserModel extends MyModel {`

**example in controller:**

```
UserModel::callStoredProcedure($stored_procedure_name, $array_of_arguments)
```

Comment: In your example the parameters are not escaped, therefore it's vulnerable to SQL-injection.

Comment: @pumbo True, but can't we make OP do some work himself?